# How do I update the element at a certain position in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have one `ArrayList` of 10 `String`s. How do I update the index `5` with another `String` value?

Comment: Very common question for people new to Java's `ArrayList<>` library.  The existence of the `set(pos, val)` method is not intuitive and doesn't fit with other Java paradigms.

Comment: when you use the data class in kotlin, as follows :
val modelData = ModelData()
listData[index] = modelData

Answer (score 350, accepted):

Let `arrList` be the `ArrayList` and `newValue` the new `String`, then just do:

```
arrList.set(5, newValue);
```

This can be found in the java api reference [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Answer (score 41):

```
list.set(5,"newString");
```

- [Reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: I think you mean index 5 as the ArrayList has only 10 elements and this would blow up. ;)

Comment: @Peter oh yeah, exchanged 5 and 10 :p

Answer (score 15):

```
 arrList.set(5,newValue);
```

and if u want to update it then add this line also

```
 youradapater.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Iterator;


 public class javaClass {

public static void main(String args[]) {


    ArrayList<String> alstr = new ArrayList<>();
    alstr.add("irfan");
    alstr.add("yogesh");
    alstr.add("kapil");
    alstr.add("rajoria");

    for(String str : alstr) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
    // update value here
    alstr.set(3, "Ramveer");
    System.out.println("with Iterator");
    Iterator<String>  itr = alstr.iterator();

    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Object obj = itr.next();
        System.out.println(obj);

    }
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

arrayList.set(location,newValue);
location= where u wnna insert, newValue= new element you are inserting.

notify is optional, depends on conditions.