# How to edit the contents of an ArrayList in-place while looping

Tags: java, string, arraylist

Assume I have an ArrayList of Strings that holds the words, "hello" and "world". I want to add the word "java" to the end of each.

I have tried to do it while looping, but did not succeed. Please suggest me a method for the same.
The other way, I found was to create a different ArrayList and copy contents, however I don't think is efficient in terms of space.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EditArrayListInLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        arrayList.add("hello");
        arrayList.add("world");

        /* This does not work */
        /*for(int i = 0;i<arrayList.size();i++)
        {
            arrayList.get(i) += "java";
        }*/

        ArrayList<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0;i<arrayList.size();i++)
        {
            String test = arrayList.get(i);
            test += "java";
            arrayList2.add(test);
        }
        System.out.println(arrayList2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352885/how-do-i-update-the-element-at-a-certain-position-in-an-arraylist

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`test += "java";` doesn't change the content of the `String` returned by `arrayList.get(i)`. It creates a new `String`. `String`s are immutable, so there isn't any way to change the `String` objects within the `List`. You can only replace them by new `String` objects.

Use `arrayList.set(index,newValue)` to replace the i'th element of the `List`:

```
for(int i = 0;i<arrayList.size();i++)
{
    arrayList.set(i,arrayList.get(i)+"java");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should manipulate the first list only. Using an another list is not an optimal solution.

Here's the code.

**Output**

```
[hellojava, worldjava]
```

**Code**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EditArrayListInLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        arrayList.add("hello");
        arrayList.add("world");

        for(int i = 0;i<arrayList.size();i++)
            arrayList.set(i, arrayList.get(i).concat("java"));

        System.out.println(arrayList);
    }
}
```

---

**Please note that `String`s are immutable.** Whenever you change the content of String, you're not actually appending anything behind the scenes. You are creating a completely new `String`.

If the contents of your `String`s are expected to change, then the advisable way is to use the `StringBuilder` class instead:

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

> The principal operations on a StringBuilder are the append and insert
>   methods, which are overloaded so as to accept data of any type. Each
>   effectively converts a given datum to a string and then appends or
>   inserts the characters of that string to the string builder. The
>   append method always adds these characters at the end of the builder;
>   the insert method adds the characters at a specified point.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EditArrayListInLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<StringBuilder> arrayList = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();

        arrayList.add(new StringBuilder("hello"));
        arrayList.add(new StringBuilder("world"));

        for(int i = 0;i<arrayList.size();i++)
            arrayList.set(i, arrayList.get(i).append("java"));

        System.out.println(arrayList);
    }
}
```

*P.S.:  If such synchronization is required then it is recommended that [StringBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) be used.*

Answer (score 2):

try using the set method.

```
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    arrayList.add("hello");
    arrayList.add("world");

    for(int i = 0;i<arrayList.size();i++)
    {
        String str = arrayList.get(i);
        arrayList.set(i, str + " java");
    }

    for(int i = 0;i<arrayList.size();i++)
    {
        String str = arrayList.get(i);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for:

```
arrayList.set(i, arrayList.get(i) + "java");
```

More info on ArrayList: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html