# How to change content of the String Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I have written this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();//declare your list
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);//create a scanner
    System.out.println("How many participants? ");
    int nbr = input.nextInt();//read the number of element
    input.nextLine();
    do {
        System.out.println("What is the name of the people?");
        list.add(input.nextLine());//read and insert into your list in one shot
        nbr--;//decrement the index
    } while (nbr > 0);//repeat until the index will be 0

    System.out.println(list);//print your list
```

The output is:

```
Jack, Frank
```

What I want to do is changing the content of the linked list. For example I wrote 2 names Jack and Frank. Then I want to add Jack's surname so that linked list will be:

```
Jack Adam, Frank
```

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update the element at a certain position in an ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352885/how-do-i-update-the-element-at-a-certain-position-in-an-arraylist)

Comment: It just changes the index of the list. For example I wrote
 list.set(0, Adam);
it just crates a new node with Adam. Doesn't change the content.

Comment: No, it changes the value **at** the index in the list. `list.set(0, "Jack Adam")` will do what you ask.

Comment: I don't want to write "Jack" again that's the problem. I want to just write Adam and it will add the "Adam" to the Jack.

Comment: Well, then you need to get and set the same index, as shown in Glim's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is use the `set` method updating the specific position that you want to update. In this case will be something like this:

```
list.set(0, list.get(0) + " Adam");
```

Notice that we are getting the content of the position 0 of the list and concatenating with the surname.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for I will mark this as a answer after  "You can accept this after x min" thing!